# Why is git only downloading part of the repository from huggingface?

Tags: git, git-lfs, huggingface

I'm trying to clone some repositories from Huggingface via git - I've installed git lfs and set up my SSH key on huggingface, I can launch the clone command on the repository I want (e.g. https://huggingface.co/google/flan-t5-xl) like so:

```
git clone git@hf.co:google/flan-t5-xl
```

This does appear to work initially:

```
Cloning into 'flan-t5-xl'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 68, done.
remote: Total 68 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 68
Receiving objects: 100% (68/68), 625.30 KiB | 6.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
Killeding content:  66% (6/9), 6.29 GiB | 3.55 MiB/s
```

However what I find downloaded in my local system is much smaller than the repository I'm pulling from, and there are multiple files missing - still using flan as my example:
[image]

(compare with the original repository:)

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've tested with multiple repositories and all behave in the same way, so I'm certain that it's something I'm doing rather than an huggingface problem

Comment: The error message at the end is "Killed" which means a) the process was interrupted in the middle, so yes, only part of the repo was cloned; and b) most probably you don't have enough (virtual) memory.

Comment: @phd you're right, I don't know why I didn't see that `Killeding` at the end there. I've bumped the RAM of the machine I'm using and it now works fine.